# How to deploy Spark Streaming application?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to deploy a Spark Streaming application on Linux server.

Can anyone provide the steps to how to deploy and what code modification require before deploy?

```
class JavaKafkaWordCount11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount11")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
        sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "20");

        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1500));

        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
        topicMap.put("TopicQueue", 20);
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
                KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, "x.xx.xxx.xxx:2181", "1", topicMap);
        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
        lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                List<String> strArray = rdd.collect();
                getProcessResult(strArray);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit your job through Spark-submit.like this..,

```
./spark-submit --class packagename.classname [--jars path to any external jars] --master local[4] "Your jar file path"
```

for any reference follow this link:

[Spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Read [Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

Yes, there's only one step required that boils down to:

1. `sbt package` which assumes you use `sbt` which for Java might be `gradle` or `maven`, though. That just says you have to package your Spark application so it's ready for deployment.
2. `spark-submit` your packaged Spark application.

You may optionally start your cluster (e.g. Spark Standalone, Apache Mesos or Hadoop YARN), but it's not really needed since `spark-submit` assumes `local[*]` by default.

p.s. You're using Apache Kafka so you have to have it up and running (at `x.xx.xxx.xxx:2181`), too.